# I have to wait some seconds before TextToSpeech speak

Tags: android, text, time, voice, speech

I have a problem with my TextToSpeech. In fact when I call my function "Son"(see below) (when I click for example) then I have to wait 4 seconds for the first click to hear the voice speaks but after the first click, it's instantaneous to hear the voice.

But sometimes it works perfectly from the first click. In the Android Monitor, if it works or not, I can see :

```
   I/TextToSpeech: Sucessfully bound to com.google.android.tts
   I/TextToSpeech: Connected to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
   I/TextToSpeech: Set up connection to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
```

So I assume that it depends on Android but I hope I can do something to correct that... Do you have any idea ? 
If you need any more information, don't hesitate to ask !

Thank you guys !

My code:

```
   public void Son(final String texte_son){
    t1=new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                t1.setLanguage(Locale.FRENCH);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    ttsGreater21(texte_son);
                } else {
                    ttsUnder20(texte_son);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void ttsUnder20(String text) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "MessageId");
    t1.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, map);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void ttsGreater21(String text) {
    String utteranceId=this.hashCode() + "";
    t1.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, utteranceId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Init TTS when application starts and store the pointer to it, do not create TTS every time when you need to synthesize a script

```
public YourActivity implements Activity {

   private Tts tts;

   void onCreate() {
       tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
           @Override
           public void onInit(int status) {
               tts.setLanguage(Locale.FRENCH);
           }
       });
   }

   void Son(String text) {
      if (tts != null) {
          HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
          map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "MessageId");
         tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, map);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Inded, it was useless to create TextToSpeech everytime. Thank you !
Nonetheless I still have my problem about waiting for the first speak. Do you have any idea how to correct that ?

Comment: I can see a difference with this code. If I wait long enough(about 6secondes so it's long) before to do my first click then the voice coming out immediately. With my previous code, waiting is useless. I don't know if that can help...

Comment: It takes some time to start the service, make the button inactive while tts is not initalized and display a progress to the user, something like that.

Comment: I delete my last comment because I was wrong. For the another application, there is the same problem. Ok So I will do that: Thank you for your help Nikolay !